# $l_2$ sequence, series with square root

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity

I'm trying to prove that the following functional is continuous:

$$\phi : \mathcal{l}_2 \ni \{x_n \} \rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}x_{3n} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}x_{2n} \in \mathbb{R}$$

When it comes to the second series, I get:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}x_{2n}  \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} | \frac{1}{n}| \cdot |x_{2n}| \le  \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}} \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_{2n}|^2} \le \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}} ||\{x_n\}|| \in \mathbb{R}$

But I don't know what to do about the first series. Is it convergent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not in general. Consider for instance $x$ such that $x_{3n}=1/(\log n\sqrt n)$ and $x_k=0$ if $k$ is not a multiple of $3$. Then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty|x_k|^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(\log n)^2}<\infty
$$
but
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\,x_{3n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n\log n}=\infty.
$$